# How do i find the rectangle width height x and y of the moving drawing line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of the class i did:

```
public static int redlinerectwidth= 0;
public static int redlinerectheight = 0;
public static int redlinerectx = 0;
public static int redlinerecty = 0;
```

Then in a method that i call it from a form i'm moving a drawn line:

```
foreach (PointF pt in MovingPoints)
            {
                if (clouds != null)
                {
                    e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, (pt.X + distance) , pt.Y , 2f, 2f);
            }   }
```

In the end in the form i know when the whole operation is ended and at this point i want to build a rectangle of the red line.

1. The first position of the red line
2. The width
3. The height
4. Thel ast position.

So it's like a rectangle.

In form1 top i added:

```
private Rectangle redlinerectangle;
```

In the form1 i have a backgroundworker and the operation end at this point:

```
if (counter == PaddingPoints.distancetoscan)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                        CloudEnteringAlert.ClearList();
                        padrectangle = PaddingPoints.rect;
                        break;
                    }
```

When the operation end i want to build the redlinerectangle from the 4 variables in the class.

How do i get the data from the clas sfrom the foreach loop and in the end create the rectangle ?

EDIT

Or better to draw also the a line on top bottom and right so it will look like a rectangle and the rectangle will get bigger once it's moving to the right. The +distance making the X coordinates to move to the right.

I'm drawing points and since the List MovingPoints have many points it look like a moving red line.
But what i see is a red line staying on place and another ed line moving to the right untill distance reach some valuei  gave it before.

foreach (Point pt in PointsInt)
            {
                e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, pt.X * (float)currentFactor, pt.Y * (float)currentFactor, 2f, 2f);
            }

First i'm drawing one still red line then i'm using the MovingPoints List and distance to move another line to the right.

How can i make that the second red line the one with the MovigPoints foreach loop will move to the right as arectangle that is build in real time when it's moving to the right ?

This is a screenshot of the end of the operation there are two red lines.
The one on the left isthe starting place and not moving. The on the right is was moving from left to right.

I need that when the second line move to the right it will show also a top and bottom lines that will get raise while it's mvonig to the right.

[image: red lines]

So in the end i will have a Rectangle.
For example a variable name rect that will be the rectangle that was drawn by the two lines in real time while the right line is moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the two for *foreach* to draw the lines. Draw the rectangle when you are moving the line once:

```
Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2);
float x, y width, height;

y = PointsInt.Min(p => p.Y);
PointF pointsIntMin = PointsInt.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with minimum Y in PointsInt list
y = PointsInt.Max(p => p.Y);
PointF pointsIntMax = PointsInt.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with maximum Y in PointsInt list

y = MovingPoints.Min(p => p.Y);
PointF movingPointsMin = MovingPoints.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with minimum Y in MovingPoints list
y = MovingPoints.Max(p => p.Y);
PointF movingPointsMax = PointsInt.First(p => p.Y == y); //point with minimum Y in MovingPoints list

x = pointsIntMin.X * (float)currentFactor;
y = pointsIntMin.Y * (float)currentFactor;
width = movingPointsMin.X + distance - x
height = (pointsIntMax.Y - pointsIntMin.Y) * (float)currentFactor;

if (clouds != null)
{
    e.DrawRectangle(myPen, (int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
}

myPen.Dispose();
```

[image]

valter